# Replication on same physical server

Tags: replication, mariadb

I am new to DB.
We have galera cluster on Test environment where mariaDB is replicated in 3 servers.
Now customer want us to work with only 1 server. they cant provide 3.

Can we do replication on single physical server?
Is it good idea? How can we achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you do that? You replicate in case the hardware dies for whatever reason. If you replicated on the same physical machine then you've got maybe a slight benefit of being able to recover data slightly easier because it's stored in multiple places on the same disk but nothing like the real benefit of replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping you're talking about MS-SQL Server.
In that case is the answer: Yes you can run it on the same server.
Is it a good idea, that depends on what you want to achieve with it and how many resources that you have on the server.

I would prefer, if one server is only possible, that you install 3 different MS-SQL Server instances on this server each with their own mry and own storage.
But understand, that in case the server goes off-line, all 3 instances are also off-line.

Proper evaluation is needed.

Comment: Hi, Ours client is government undertaking, they always cry for money, so they don't provide more servers.